# Will this SE always be accessible as programmers.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, new-site-name

As the title says: will this SE always be accessible as https://programmers.stackexchange.com?

I still access it by typing `pr` in my browser's address bar because its official name shares a long prefix with https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.  Selecting what I meant by `so` from the history drop-down is, like, two extra keystrokes.  And worse, I'd actually have to look at the menu items instead of relying on muscle memory. The horror!

Comment: I wonder how many external links would break by removing the alias.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no reason to break old links pointing here from elsewhere on the web.  This site has URL aliases https://programmers.stackexchange.com and https://programmer.stackexchange.com which is pretty common on SE. The API shows the [list of all aliases](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!.UDMsw2*Hs-oA4dr&run=true): for example, one can access Electronics site by going to http://chiphacker.com, or the Mathematics site by going to one of

- https://math.stackexchange.com or
- https://mathematics.stackexchange.com or
- https://maths.stackexchange.com

These aliases exist for ~7 years (as long as the site itself). The old Programmers URL is just another one of those.

Comment: *7 years...!?* I'm getting old.